# As a contractor should I bill my hours even if there's no work?

Tags: ethics, contracting

I have a contract with a fairly large company doing a specialized task. The contract states I will work a maximum of 10 hours a week for 8 months.

Because of this, I have allocated 10 hours a week of my availability towards this contract. The thing is the work is not consistent. Sometimes they need me to work, and some weeks they have nothing for me to do. It really goes day by day. I invoice monthly and the month end for the first month is coming up. Realistically this month I have probably worked 10 hours of the 40 my contract states.

My hourly rate is not high, so in my mind this is really not costing them much to begin with if I bill the full 40 every month. I feel like if I only bill the 10 it's not worth my time.

I'm fairly new to the entire contracting thing as I still maintain my full time job, so I have absolutely no experience with this situation. What is the thing to do here? It seems like they are just slow and unorganized on their end and things may pick up in the next few months.

EDIT:

The wording in the contract is exactly as follows in regards to hours per week:

"This contract is to provide services when required for (specialized task) and
it is not anticipated that this will exceed 10 hours per week."

In addition, my hourly rate is ~$30/hour which is basically nothing, the company I have the contract with is worth upwards of 1 billion.

I'm mainly wondering if you think think they will have any issues with me billing the full 10 hours a week.

Comment: I see that this was migrated from sever fault, but I really think that this is a question for the [Freelancing Stack Exchange](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com)

Comment: It is appropriate for Workplace, since the same principles may apply for hourly non-freelance positions

Comment: `This contract is to provide services when required for (specialized task) and it is not anticipated that this will exceed 10 hours per week.` - Based on that wording, if I were the customer, I'd assume that I am paying you only for actual hours worked.

Comment: OF COURSE it's $300 a week dude.  Good lord.   ***This is a totally common arrangement.  The hours etc. are just nominal.***

Comment: Your time is evidently worth $30 per hour. I don't see how the total hours worked affects what is "worth your time", as you've already agreed that it's worth $30 for every hour. If you work only 10 hours in a month, you haven't lost anything, as you only spent 10 hours of your time.

Comment: How easy is it to get out of the contract?  You say you have to allocate ten hours a week for it:  do you know in advance whether you're getting work or not?  Are you in some sort of on call situation, or could you go play tennis in this time if there's no work?

Comment: @Fattie are you saying of course meaning bill them 10 hours, or of course I shouldn't?

Comment: @NuclearWang by not working the 10 hours in the contract weekly, but expecting to potentially have to, I've essentially lost out on 10 hours I could have worked elsewhere/on another contract. I can't take on other jobs just expecting to not receive the work from this one.

Comment: @DavidThornley it's really day by day. I may get an email saying they need something done today, or by the end of the week.

Comment: @BelginFish , in my opinion, **yes the ten hours**.  Note that my answer saying such got many downvotes.  For me it is very obvious and common in the industry, in the exact type of circumstances and company you describe, that you'd bill the ten hours.  Many here disagree.   **I do not see any downside** to doing so - at worst they will reply "we don't agree" and then you will say "thanks and goodbye".

Comment: My God, there's now a separate site "freelancing stack exchange" ?  That's this site.

Comment: @Fattie I ended up emailing them about it. Not only are they expecting me to bill the 10 hours just because I'm on hand, they also mentioned that there may be more work than was initially anticipated so to bill over the 10 hours if I end up spending too much time in any given week. I understand that everyone else's answers may have been correct on paper, but yours seems to be the winner when it comes to real life.

Comment: hi @BelginFish - sure, that is the obvious outcome.  Thanks for the "tick" on the answer!  :)

Answer (score -16, accepted):

It is highly likely that:

***In the actual circumstances/corporation you describe:***

## of course

they are expecting you to simply bill the fixed $300 a week.

It's a token amount of money weekly. Naturally there's fine print in all directions in any "standard contract, grab a PDF."

For such a tiny amount of money, based on ***the actual circumstances/corporation you describe*** it is incredibly unlikely they are envisaging you recording hours, worrying about the exact amount of time, etc.

---

## "I'm mainly wondering if you think think they will have any issues with me billing the full 10 hours a week..."

***In the actual circumstances/corporation you describe*** it is almost certainly the case they simply expect you will be paid the $300 a week.  It's a "$300 a week contract".

(At worst they reply - and this would be astounding, utterly bizarre - "we were thinking of paying you $30 a week some weeks". In which case you would obviously say "thanks and goodbye".)

Comment: I don't know why you think "it's a $300 a week contract". That is not stated or implied in the question.

Comment: Because it is *absolutely commonplace in the industry* to do this.

Comment: Further to @GendoIkari 's comment, the contract language we did actually get in the question specifically mentions performing specific tasks. To me, this contract language reads about as far as possible from a blanket retainer contract.

Comment: He never even specified what industry it was; so you can't know that. And even if it is common, it doesn't mean that it's what is happening in this case. I have been a software contractor for multiple different companies, and in every case I had a contract where I only got paid by the hour, with no minimum guarantee, for hours I worked.

Comment: It is *amazing* that anyone with any experience in the industry would think what you guys are saying.

Comment: The contract states that it's not anticipated that the job takes more than 10 hours a week, which I interpret to mean that 90% of the time, the job will take less than 10 hours a week. Why should the employer pay for 10 hours when they know that the job doesn't take that long 90% of the time? The dollar amount of the contract doesn't really seem relevant, as the OP either deserves the money or does not, regardless of how much it is.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere , that is not sensible.  It is a job for a tiny, minuscule, amount of money.  It's just a retainer to ask a few questions a week, if anything comes up that week.  It's totally normal with contracts (in any field) that there is wiggle language (so that one party or the other can bust the contract if they feel like it) which is outside the sense of the deal.

Comment: "Because it is absolutely commonplace in the industry to do this", you mean commit billing fraud?  The language specifically says "provide services when required".   Billing for time when you didn't work because it wasn't required is wrong.

Comment: A normal, full-time employee has a contract that states that they will receive an annual salary; which is not dependent upon hours worked.

Comment: @Fattie Either you don't understand the difference between a full-time salaried employee and an hourly contractor, or you're being purposefully obtuse, but either way, it doesn't make me trust this answer any more.

Comment: At least if I'm ever looking to hire a contractor, I know where not to look.

Comment: One way to help understand this common situation, if you don't have much experience in the field.  Say the question was identical, but it was for one hour a week at $10 for the hour.  I'm guessing, you would then say "Sure, you bill the $10 a week. It's just nominal and of course they don't want you to bill $3.18, $4.22 etc."  That applies at the tiny amount of money described in the actual question.

Comment: No actually. My contracts generally have stated that billing will be done in 15 minute increments, so if my hourly rate is $90 per hour, and I only work for 10 minutes one week, then I bill $22.50 for that week, as stated in the contract.

Comment: If on the other hand, the contract stated that billing is in hourly increments, then you would bill for a full hour for any small amount of work.

Comment: The mods delete comment chains (which they don't like) so this one will be here forever as a discussion anyway, so not to fear.

Comment: I ended up emailing them about it. Not only are they expecting me to bill the 10 hours just because I'm on hand, they also mentioned that there may be more work than was initially anticipated so to bill over the 10 hours if I end up spending too much time in any given week. I understand that everyone else's answers may have been correct on paper, but yours seems to be the winner when it comes to real life.

Comment: The fact that this particular contractor's employer is ok with the contract being a retainer does not in any way mean that it is a good idea to assume that this would be true for any other contract.

Comment: Regarding this bizarre and polarizing QA.  I've realized what is confusing folks is this:  The question mentions some language from the PDF thingy that was bandied about when the work began.  If you haven't done much contracting (whether as an individual or a small company, or whatever) the literal contracts themselves (the PDF you glance at an e-sign) are inevitably garbage.  (Big companies, contracting agencies, and the 2 or 3 talent agents are the worst offenders.)  They're as shoddily done, "copy/paste", as NDAs.  That seems to be the  source of confusion.  Anyways.  Bottoms up.

Comment: @BelginFish Given that you ended up emailing them about it, it's not clear to me how this answer ended up being helpful in any way. This answer did not advise you to email them about it; it advised you to make an assumption without asking. Shouldn't the "accepted" answer be one that tells you to email them and ask?

Comment: @GendoIkari - you're being embarrassing dude.  When you're wrong, you're wrong.  Relax  :)   The mods won't delete this comment chain - since it's not one the mods disagree with.  So your comments will be here forever.

Comment: @Fattie This has nothing to do with our particular disagreement... your answer ended up matching what the company told him to do; your answer did NOT match what he ended up doing; which was to ask the company. I don't see anything in your answer that helped lead him towards asking the company about it; so it's not clear to me how his end result ended up being any different due to this answer.

Comment: Normally, the accepted answer is the one found to be most helpful. Not the one that ended up stating what ended up being true. Of course, OP is free to accept whatever answer they want.

Comment: G dude, (1) **read the question title**.  (2) Myself (and one or two other people) gave the correct answer. ("Yes" for the question asked about (obviously) the specific situation described.)  OP even checked and **indeed it is the correct answer.**  You are bordering on metaphysics .. answers should be helpful not correct .. what??  Let's drop it!   As I mention, the mods won't delete this comment chain - since it's not one the mods disagree with. So your comments will be here forever.

Comment: As a curiosity - *going further than answering the question and on to general advice* - in fact I would have suggested to the OP to not ask for clarification!  The reasoning is "don't rock a boat".  (Actually, i was thinking of mentioning this in the answer .. "Furthermore ..."   But everyone hates answers that go beyond the question and blab advice.)

Comment: And furthermore!!   Say that  - incredibly - the answer to the phone call had been "oh, we want you to bill thirty whole dollars some weeks".  This answer would *still* be the correct one because overwhelmingly usually in the situation described, the intent would have been the $300 a week.  So there!  :)

Answer (score 28):

You'd bill for the hours you worked.  If you worked 10 hours this month, bill 10 hours.

If you want to bill 10 hours a week whether or not they have work for you, that's something that you'd need to include in the contract you negotiate.  Rather than just specifying a maximum number of hours, specify a minimum number of hours and potentially something about when they need to provide work in order to use their hours for that week.

Comment: I agree with this answer but think it would be worth updating to mention that renegotiating a small contract like this should not be a big deal. Reach out to the business contact, explain there is less work than anticipated, and state they are can't continue to offer your services under these terms. Maybe OP needs a weekly minimum billing regardless of hours worked, a higher hourly rate, or just needs to offer services on a non-hourly fixed-rate basis with a cap on the total hours spent per month.  This is a problem OP and the client should be able to solve together.

Comment: @CameronRoberts - It shouldn't be too big a deal to have negotiated a minimum number of hours at the beginning or to renegotiate when the contract expires.  Sometimes, though, part of being a contractor is that you have to live with a less-than-ideal-in-hindsight agreement.  It isn't clear to me whether this is a "live and learn" situation or a "tell the client that you're going to exercise your option to terminate the contract early if something doesn't change".

Answer (score 7):

This is entirely dependent upon your contract. What does your contract state? Does it state hourly billing for hours worked or does it state retainer billing for a monthly block of hours with a "use it or lose it" provision?

The most important thing you can do as an independent/freelance consultant is to make sure your contract spells out in specific details the exact terms of your engagement. This includes things like scheduling, availability, hourly rate, hourly commitment (how many hours per week/month), overages, underages, discounts, after hours work, travel costs, etc., etc. The second most important thing you can do is to purchase professional/business liability insurance.

Below is a boilerplate hourly contract that I use. I start with this and tailor it to the specific client:

> By signing this agreement, **[CLIENT NAME]** (Client) has retained
>   **[SERVICE PROVIDER NAME]** (Service Provider) to provide Information
>   Technology related services for the period **[START DATE]** to **[END DATE]**,
>   and agrees to the terms and conditions as set forth in this Agreement.
>
> During this period, Service Provider agrees to provide Information
>   Technology related services at the rate of $ **[HOURLY RATE]** per hour on
>   assignments to be determined by Client. Work will normally be
>   performed at the offices of Service Provider but may take place at
>   other locations as required by Client. Work will normally occur
>   between the hours of 9 AM to 5 PM, Monday through Friday. Unscheduled
>   or emergency work performed outside of these hours will be billed at
>   the rate of $ **[After Hours Rate]** per hour. Scheduled after
>   hours work will be subject to the standard hourly rate. All scheduled
>   after hours work must be scheduled a minimum of 7 days in advance.
>
> Payment for these services will be made to Service Provider upon
>   receipt of Service Provider invoice. A monthly invoice will be
>   submitted to Client no later than the 5th of the month immediately
>   following the month in which the work was performed.
>
> All expenses exclusive of normal overhead are not included in this
>   agreement and will be billed separately. Examples of such expenses
>   are: delivery services, long distance telephone calls, and all
>   expenses related to travel such as travel time, mileage, meals, and
>   accommodations. All travel time to work locations other than Client
>   office is billable. Mileage of more than 25 miles for travel to work
>   sites will be submitted as an expense at the current IRS Standard
>   Mileage Rate. All invoices are payable upon receipt.
>
> All materials furnished by Client will remain the property of Client
>   and will be returned upon request or upon termination of this agreement.
>
> The results of any and all work performed by Service Provider for
>   Client will remain the property of the Client. Client may use this
>   material in any way deemed appropriate.
>
> This agreement shall be subject to voluntary termination, without
>   cause, by either party. Any rights to compensation or remuneration of
>   any kind are to terminate at the time this agreement terminates.
>
> Each party agrees to indemnify, defend, and hold harmless the other
>   party from and against any loss, cost, or damage of any kind
>   (including reasonable outside attorneys’ fees) to the extent arising
>   out of its breach of this Agreement, and/or its negligence or willful
>   misconduct.

Comment: It turns out it was *totally incorrect*, as myself and a few people pointed out.  In the actual situation given it's completely obvious that it was a "$300 a week job" (and the boilerplate language on some standard work contract, was irrelevant).

Answer (score 4):

This question might be a legal one: *Can* you bill them for hours not worked under this contract?

That aside, based on what you posted, it sounds like you are placed in a situation where they will give you work to do and expect you to do it and bill them for the time you spent on it.  If there is no work, then they don't ask you to do anything, and you have that time "off", so to speak.  Presumably you are not "on-call", i.e. if they call you and say you need to do something, then it doesn't need to be done immediately; you can schedule it amongst your other priorities as long as it is done in a reasonable time frame.

If this is the case, then I wouldn't bill them.  You aren't working during the time you don't have work to do, and you are not expected to respond urgently to requests.  Take that extra time and do what you want.

However, if you have a tight SLA (e.g. for 10 hours/week you have to be glued to your computer waiting for work to come in, and that's in your contract), then I would bill them all 10 hours.  The difference is, if you are or are not able to use that extra time when you aren't working as your own time, or do you still have to keep up responsibilities to this company?  Any time you are keeping up responsibilities to this company should be billable hours, even if it's not "work", so to speak.  Any time you have no responsibilities to this company, are not billable.

Answer (score -1):

> Sometimes they need me to work, and some weeks they have nothing for me to do.

There is ***always*** something to do.

- Is the documentation 100% complete? Is there any more which you can review?
- Is the code 100% compiler warning free (if applicable)? Have you Linted it (static code analysis)?
- Are there enough unit tests (100% code coverage)? Software integration tests?
- Could the code be refactored?
- Do you have a continuous integration system, such as Jenkins?
- Are there any future projects you could acquaint yourself with?

Also, you don't state what happens if you need more than 10 hours in a given week – do invoice the extra?

Personally, I would treat it as a retainer. Look at it as them paying you (rather little, as you say), to be available ***should they need you***.

Comment: If the company had intended for this to be a retainer then the contract would have been worded that way. Spending time & billing for work they didn't ask for or approve is not likely to end well imo.

Comment: That is **simply completely wrong**, @brhans .  One can use any term one likes (retainer, expert advice contract, limited funds contract, etc) or one can use no terms at all.   It is completely standard in the business that such a contract means "you get $300 a week to be on hand for expert QA".   Note that ***even in a salaried full-time job*** it is utterly normal that often you don't work anything like 40 hours in a given week.  t's a $300 a week expert-advice contract, end of story.

Comment: This answer seems to focus on software development despite the question not specifying that. Further, the question mentions that the contract is for specific, specialized tasks. It doesn't seem clear that this applies. If the contract is for mowing the lawn, the customer probably doesn't want you writing documentation on how to change the lawnmower's oil, or spending time pruning trees. And especially not billing for days/weeks where they didn't ask you to mow at all.

Comment: Then all that the OP can do is to ask the employer. Although, if it were me I would find a way to let them know that if they only give a few paid hours most week, then I would rather not and they should look for someone else

Comment: @Fattie - the OP doesn't specify what the nature of the business is, and the contract specifies that services will be provided *when required*, and billed hourly. There is no evidence in the OP's question that the customer should expect to be paying a fixed 10-hour/week rate whether or not services are performed.

Comment: @Mawg - customers don't and shouldn't pay for undocumented and un-requested "busy" work unless they have you on a retainer and you're trying to give them value for their money. The contract as described by the OP does not sound like a retainer contract to me. He would be completely unjustified in billing them for hours in which he performed no work. The contract should explicitly define the terms of the engagement, and in it's current state is lacking anything that infers any type of payment for hours where no work was performed.

Comment: @Fattie - it's not completely standard in the business that a contract means "you get paid no matter what.". The contract should explicitly describe and define the terms of the engagement, including the payment structure (retainer or hourly).

Comment: @joeqwerty - there's been a lot of commentary on this QA.  All I can say is in this *actual specific* case, in my opinion, and based on (vast) experience, the situation is simply that you'd bill 10 hours a week.  It's totally commonplace that the exact wording does not reflect the sense of the arrangement.